# Function With/Without Passing an argument - PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, null, arguments

Below is a function I created for inserting break lines.

It works fine like this; br(2); //any number, 2 as an example.

However I would like it to work if I typed just br(); it will use 1, but if I specify a number it will use that. Sort of as a default value if none is specified, I've looked throughout google, but can't find the right words to search and find te answer I suppose.

```
function br($i) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j <= $i) {
        echo '<br />';
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `str_repeat('<br>', $i)`

Comment: See [Example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Wha.. no espresso? *hmph!*

Comment: You can have espresso if you'd like @Fred-ii-. I'm no cappuccino fan myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a default value:

```
function br($i = 1) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j <= $i) {
        echo '<br />';
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Reference: [PHP Manual - Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: This works great, thank you. I am new to programming and did not realize I could do it like this, should have tried though. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You want [Default Parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). Maybe just:

```
function br($i=1) {
    echo str_repeat('<br />', $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 as the default

```
function br($i = 1) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j <= $i) {
        echo '<br />';
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function br($count = 1)
{
    while($count) {
        echo '<br />';
        $count--;
    }
}
```

The "$count = 1" part designates $count as an optional parameter.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default